# Comparing two python lists to find differences and ignoring spelling mistakes

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, fuzzy-comparison

I have two excel sheets and am building a small program to compare two columns from these sheets to find the differences. The problem is, since most of these inputs are done manually there are a lot of spelling errors, which should be ignored. The program should highlight new or deleted data.

I was reading about fuzzy text and I found this code online ([link](https://pypi.org/project/two-lists-similarity/)) but the output of this just generates a CSV with exact same entries (not what I wanted). I'll still add it here so you've an idea what I'm talking about.

```
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter
import collections
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
import time
from two_lists_similarity import Calculate_Similarity as cs

#the first file
book_old = pd.read_excel(r' #Input file here', sheet_name = '#Sheet Name Here')
data_old = book_old.iloc[7:,2].tolist()
#Selecting the column i want to compare

#second file to compare with
book_new = pd.read_excel(r'#source here', sheet_name = '#Sheet name')
data_new = book_new.iloc[7:,2].tolist() #selecting col

inp_list = data_old
ref_list = data_new
#this is what i picked up online because i couldnt do myself
#the plan is to iterate the list and find entries that are different, ignore spellings
# Create an instance of the class. This is otherwise called as an object 
csObj = cs(inp_list,ref_list)
# csObj is now the object of Calculate Similarity class. 
csObj.fuzzy_match_output(output_csv_name = 'pkg_sim_test_vsc.csv', output_csv_path = r'#Output path')
```

Comment: You're trying to tell the computer to tell if a word is the same as another word with a spelling mistake? That is incredibly hard, how is it meant to know if words are the same when technically, they are different?

Comment: I was thinking of setting a minimum ratio? like for when the similarity is greater than 75% we assume it's just a spelling mistake and not a whole new word. There will obviously be false positives be we wanna get them as low as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is probably some function that computes *how different* two strings are.

Turns out there are already some algorithms for that! Check out the **[Damerau–Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damerau%E2%80%93Levenshtein_distance)**, which seems to be the closest to your use-case. From Wikipedia:

> Informally, the Damerau–Levenshtein distance between two words is the minimum number of operations (consisting of insertions, deletions or substitutions of a single character, or transposition of two adjacent characters) required to change one word into the other.

However, this will only pick up on simple typos and is prone to false positives, so you may want to combine it with some other mechanism.

There are Python implementations of this algorithm on the web (see [here](https://www.guyrutenberg.com/2008/12/15/damerau-levenshtein-distance-in-python/) or [there](https://gist.github.com/pombredanne/0d83ad58f45986ddeb0917266e106be0)).

Alternatively, feel free to check out some other algorithms like:

- the [Hamming distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance)
- the [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance)

Comment: Thanks for this! So the idea here is to run these for every string ie each element of the list and iterate through the list?

Comment: Yep. You can compare every pair of words that you _expect_ to be equal and check if the return value of your distance function is "low enough". What "low enough" is, is up to you ;)

Comment: @appleofreak if the answer helped you, feel free to give it an upvote, then click the checkmark to accept the answer :)